# SQL Server - boolean literal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean, literals

How to write literal boolean value in SQL Server? See sample use:

```
select * from SomeTable where PSEUDO_TRUE
```

another sample:

```
if PSEUDO_TRUE
begin
  select 'Hello, SQL!'
end
```

Note: The query above has nothing to do with how I'm going to use it. It is just to test the literal boolean.

Comment: No, just want to see if true works in where  clause. First off, I don't know the literal for true and false.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a Boolean data type nor the required operators `IS TRUE`, `IS UNKNOWN`, etc (though the SQL-99 Standard has both). A common workaround is to use a `CHAR(1)` column constrained `CHECK (col1 IN ('T', 'F'))`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a boolean [data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx). As @Mikael has indicated, the closest approximation is the bit. But that is a numeric type, not a boolean type. In addition, it only supports 2 values - `0` or `1` (and one non-value, `NULL`).

SQL (standard SQL, as well as T-SQL dialect) describes a [Three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). The boolean type for SQL should support 3 values - `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN` (and also, the non-value `NULL`). So `bit` isn't actually a good match here.

Given that SQL Server has no support for the *data type*, we should not expect to be able to write literals of that "type".

Comment: I wonder what could have made the SQL Server team to have bit instead of boolean data type (with values true and false). Boolean is so natural across all application domains. I believe they would still be using 1 byte in storage to store the bit data type. Even with internal storage as bit they could have supported `True` and `False` as syntactic sugar in the SQL scripts at least.

Comment: Odds are because it's that way in C. There are no such values `true` or `false`, but instead truthy (not 0) and falsy (0) values.  C99 added stdbool.h, which only defines the macros for these, but at post processing any such values are replaced with 1 and 0 respectively.

Answer (score 48):

```
select * from SomeTable where 1=1
```

Comment: It works! Unfortunately it's not a literal, the result of `1=1` is boolean true but it's not literal.

Answer (score 28):

Most databases will accept this:

```
select * from SomeTable where true
```

However some databases (eg SQL Server, Oracle) do not have a boolean type. In these cases you may use:

```
select * from SomeTable where 1=1
```

BTW, if building up an sql where clause by hand, this is the basis for simplifying your code because you can avoid having to know if the condition you're about to add to a where clause is the *first* one (which should be preceded by `"WHERE"`), or a *subsequent* one (which should be preceded by `"AND"`). By always starting with `"WHERE 1=1"`, all conditions (if any) added to the where clause are preceded by `"AND"`.

Comment: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'group'` I'm using MSSQL

Comment: Dear downvoters: The initial question I answered did **not** specify the server type "sql-server", so I answered the generic question with a generic answer with the caveat of "most databases". I fail to see why this deserves a downvote.

Comment: You better remove your answer before you get any more downvotes. Somehow it's my fault that I just indicated `SQL` not `MSSQL`.

Comment: @dpp is the answer acceptable now? I've given an alternative that *all* databases will accept

Comment: Every Microsoft SQL server is a SQL database server, buit not every SQL database server is a *Microsoft* SQL server. Just as every apple is a fruit, but not every fruit is an apple (or perhaps in MS case, a pear :)

Answer (score 18):

This isn't mentioned in any of the other answers. If you want a value that orms (should) hydrate as boolean you can use

CONVERT(bit, 0) -- false
CONVERT(bit, 1) -- true

This gives you a bit which is not a boolean. You cannot use that value in an if statement for example:

```
IF CONVERT(bit, 0)
BEGIN
    print 'Yay'
END
```

woudl not parse. You would still need to write

```
IF CONVERT(bit, 0) = 0
```

So its not terribly useful.

Answer (score 16):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx):
syntax for searching is

```
[ WHERE <search_condition> ]*
```

And search condition is:

```
<search_condition> ::= 
    { [ NOT ] <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } 
    [ { AND | OR } [ NOT ] { <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } ] 
[ ,...n ]
```

And predicate is:

```
<predicate> ::= 
    { expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } expression
```

As you can see, you **always** have to write two expressions to compare.
Here search condition is  **boolean expression** like 1=1, a!=b

Do not confuse search expressions with **boolean constants** like **'True'** or **'False'**. You can assign boolean constants to BIT variables

```
DECLARE @B BIT
SET @B='True'
```

but in TSQL you can not use boolean constants instead of boolean expressions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Somewhere WHERE 'True'
```

It will not work.

But you can use boolean constants to build two-sided search expression like this:

```
SEARCH * FROM Somewhere WHERE 'True'='True'
```

Answer (score 11):

SQL Server does not have literal true or false values. You'll need to use the `1=1` method (or similar) in the rare cases this is needed.

One option is to create your own named variables for true and false

```
DECLARE @TRUE bit
DECLARE @FALSE bit
SET @TRUE = 1
SET @FALSE = 0

select * from SomeTable where @TRUE = @TRUE
```

But these will only exist within the scope of the batch (you'll have to redeclare them in every batch in which you want to use them)

Comment: This doesn't work as explained in the answers above. "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@TRUE'"

Comment: +1 this worked for me in `case when exists(
   select 1 from project.quota_group_supplier qgs with (nolock) where qgs.project_quota_id=qg.project_quota_id) then @TRUE else @FALSE end `

Answer (score 6):

You can use the values `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`.
From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql:

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE
>   is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? It should work just fine in WHERE clauses.

Comment: E.g. `select 'TRUE' where 'TRUE'`. Neither can it be used meaningfully in the select-context, nor does the where-clause work. The SQL-Parser complains about 'TRUE' not being boolean. Likewise `select TRUE where TRUE` is invalid in both parts. All in all. It does not generally work on MS-SQL.

Comment: Ok, but it does work when comparing a value, such as `WHERE column = 'TRUE'` or `IF @value = 'FALSE'`.

Answer (score 5):

> How to write literal boolean value in SQL Server?
>   select * from SomeTable where PSEUDO_TRUE

There is no such thing.

You have to compare the value with something using `= < > like ...`. The closest you get a boolean value in SQL Server is the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx). And that is an integer that can have the values `null`, `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider that a "true value" is everything except 0 and not only 1.
So instead of 1=1 you should write 1<>0.

Because when you will use parameter (@param <> 0) you could have some conversion issue.

The most know is Access which translate True value on control as -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'True' or 'False' strings for simulate bolean type data.

```
Select *
From <table>
Where <columna> = 'True'
```

I think this way maybe slow than just put 1 because it's resolved with Convert_implicit function.

Answer (score 1):

I question the value of using a Boolean in TSQL. 
Every time I've started wishing for Booleans & For loops I realised I was approaching the problem like a C programmer & not a SQL programmer. The problem became trivial when I switched gears.

In SQL you are manipulating SETs of data. "WHERE BOOLEAN" is ineffective, as does not change the set you are working with. You need to compare each row with something for the filter clause to be effective. The Table/Resultset ***is*** an iEnumerable, the SELECT statement ***is*** a FOREACH loop.

Yes, "WHERE IsAdmin = True" is nicer to read than "WHERE IsAdmin = 1"

Yes, "WHERE True" would be nicer than "WHERE 1=1, ..." when dynamically generating TSQL.

and maybe, passing a Boolean to a stored proc may make an if statement more readable.

But mostly, the more IF's, WHILE's & Temp Tables you have in your TSQL, the more likely you should refactor it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers the intent of the question.  Although there are no Booleans in SQL Server, if you have a database that had Boolean types that was translated from Access, the phrase which works in Access was "...WHERE Foo" (Foo is the Boolean column name).  It can be replaced by "...WHERE Foo<>0" ... and this works.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from SomeTable where null is null
```

or

```
select * from SomeTable where null is not null
```

maybe this is the best performance?