# SQL Server boolean operators

Tags: sql-server-2005

I know that SQL Server does not have boolean data type and your best option is to use BIT data type.

My question is to what boolean expressions evaluate. For example if I have the statement

```
expr1 AND expr2
```

and if expr1 is true and expr2 is false, do they internally evaluate to BITs with values 1 and 0? And then the AND operator checks for BITs?

I think this is not the case because then the following should work:

```
select 1 where 1 and 0
```

So does sql server internally have a boolean data type?

The following work

```
select 1 where 1 = 0
select 1 where 1 = 0 and 0 = 0
```

but this

```
select 1 where 1 and 0
```

reports

Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

which means that internally sql server handles the expressions as booleans, but why don't have access to that data type.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, I didn't understand

Comment: I didn't use bitwise. You did't understand my question.

Comment: Since you can't *store* the result of an expression evaluation, nor provide a value in place of one being evaluated, what's the point?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170688/sql-server-boolean-literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does have a `Boolean` data type. You can open the [Logical Operators (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773.aspx) manual page and find the following statement:

> Logical operators test for the truth of some condition. Logical operators, like comparison operators, return a **Boolean** data type with a value of TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN.

It's just that you can't use this type in the same way you can use other Transact-SQL data types. For instance, you can't declare boolean variables or arguments, add boolean columns to tables, cast to/from a boolean. But you *can* have boolean *expressions* and use them in contexts where they are required (`WHERE`, `ON`, check constraints…). You can also apply boolean *operators* to those expressions: `AND`, `NOT` et al. (Operators like `<`, `=`, `LIKE` and other can also be considered boolean, in the sense that they *return* boolean results, but their operands are actually never booleans.)

So, to summarise, there *is* a boolean type in SQL Server but its use is limited, as described above. Why? My answer may be a silly one, sorry, but that's one that I'm satisfied with: this is the way they chose it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Logical operators results in true or false. So in your example you get a result if `expr1` and `expr2` is true. To check if its true or not is the operation you do for each expression.

So you compare e.g. a column against something like a bit value `column_bit = 0` and this results in true or false.
If your `expr1` is true and `expr2` is false your result is false for the logical AND operator.

Edit:

Your `select 1 where 1 and 0` can't work because you don't use a compare operator. 1=1 AND 0=0 works e.g. but its nonsense :)

Comment: I understand what you say. My question was how does sql server handles these boolean values true, false, unknown.

Comment: I know it can't work and why! It seems I can't explain correctly what I'm asking!

Comment: Well logical operators handles true/false for each operation but there is no "i am true/false placeholder" for a operation, so you need always to compare against something.